# How do I position a svg point exactly half way

Tags: css, svg

How do I make a coordinate be in the half point of my website no matter the width of the website, basically how do I do this

```
<path d=" M0 0 L50% 300 L100% 0" stroke="white" fill="yellow"></path>
```

expect since svg doesn't allow % how do I write this in svg proper form, if anyone can answer my question I will be very thankful

Comment: The svg element needs to have a viewBox attribute. For example if the viewBox = "0 0 100 300" the d attribute of the path needs fo be d="M0,0L**50**,300L**100**,0" If the svg element has a viewBox but no width and/or height it will stretch to take all the width available

Comment: Can you be more concrete. What do you mean by "SVG point"? Is it placing the SVG element/document on a webpage - basically styling using CSS or is it placing a SVG element like the path in the center of the SVG itself?

Comment: happy holidays @exeneta you were right about the view box and the width does stretch out but the height does too as well to the end of the page and no mater what i do i cant make it be 400px, if I give it the attribute height: 400px it will break the width as well i tried some other stuff with some divs but they also didn't work, how would you solve the problem?

Comment: In this case you won't respect the aspect ratio. If this is your wish you can use width="100%" height="400" and a [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute to let you either stretch or slice the drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a viewbox with preserveAspectRatio="none" set to none, like this

```
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="1200px" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<path d="M0 13 L100 0 L100 100 L0 100 Z " fill="#14305D"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top of this triangle will always be at the center of the page.

Is that helpful?

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body:before, body:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
}

body:before {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

body:after {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M10 90 L50 50 L90 90"></path>
</svg>
```